# "Invalid ns" when connecting to mongodb server

Tags: php, codeigniter, mongodb, mlab, mediatemple

Im trying to connect to a MongoLabs mongodb server I setup for a small project Im working on. I can connect fine when connecting from my local machine, but when I try to make a connection from my Mediatemple server I get a 'Invalid ns' error:

```
Unable to connect to MongoDB: Failed to connect to: dsXXXXXX.mongolab.com:27769: send_package: the query returned a failure: Invalid ns [XXXXXX_dev/XXXXXX_dev.$cmd] (code: 16256)
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this would be a major help.

Comment: Well the problem is clearly in the part you are **not** showing, which is the connection string you **are** using. Perhaps an edit to include this without **fully** giving away your credentials.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perhaps your database name in your connection string or collection name ([together they make a namespace](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-namespace)) have special characters, and they make the namespace name illegal.

So you should make sure your connection string is ok.

For example, mine looks like

```
mongodb://mydblogin:mydbpassword@ds044444.mongolab.com:44444/mydatabase
```

Also make sure that collection name is legal.

Comment: In my case, the database name was empty.