# WriteConcernException: mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Error:
[WriteConcernException: { "serverUsed" : "localhost/127.0.0.1:27017" , "err" : "Invalid ns [Vsic.]" , "code" : 16257 , "n" : 0 , "connectionId" : 169 , "ok" : 1.0}]

Hi to all i am  using mongodb with play webframework. About the setup I am using ubuntu in inside a vmware workstation where the webserver is hosted and written few html pages and  source data through froms and then to databse. I am able to do write in to databse when using ubuntu (browsing) where as if i come out of the virtual machine acesss outside the machine  able to acess the form and able to fill the data in the form when writing the data to DB i get the above error.

code:
     public class DataConn {
    //connection to the exsisting database
    private String Dbname ;
    private String User;
    private String password;
    private String Coll_name;
    private DB Db_client;

/**set and get methods ***/

```
public boolean connect() throws UnknownHostException {
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );
    Db_client = mongoClient.getDB(Dbname);
    boolean check = Db_client.authenticate(User,password.toCharArray());

    return check;


}

public boolean check_collection(String name){
    return Db_client.collectionExists(name);

}
```

// exception  is thrown by this method

```
enter code here
public boolean create_collection(String name,profile p_obj){
    //use
    if (!check_collection(name)){
        Jongo jongo = new Jongo(Db_client);
        MongoCollection collection = jongo.getCollection(name);
        collection.save(p_obj);
        return true;

    }

    return false;


}
```

---

calling  method

```
        DataConn db_obj = new DataConn("Vsic","vsic","vsic");
        db_obj.connect();
        profile profile_obj = proForm.get();
        name = profile_obj.getProfilename();
        profile_obj.setStore_object(con_instance);
        db_obj.create_collection(profile_obj.getProfilename(), profile_obj);
        play.Logger.info("completed scanning saving into database");
        String temp = session().get("User");
        session().clear();
        session().put("User",temp);
        System.out.println(session().toString());
        //db_obj.close();

    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: You need to provide more info like the code you are running. Just the error alone isn't enough.

Comment: joao i have posted the code thank you

Comment: Look at the error you're receiving: "err" : "Invalid ns [Vsic.]". This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21827892/invalid-ns-when-connecting-to-mongodb-server

Comment: Hassan thank you however i am able to connect to the database and read values however i cannot write them

Comment: Got to know the issue the it was a from data mistake giving the collection name as empty string Thank you for ur valuable advice